# Module parse failed: Unexpected token after running eject

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babeljs

Hopefully a quick solution for this one.
I've just done an eject on a React app built in typescript to see if I can get a different problem working.
On trying to compile, I now get this error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (27:19)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     }).catch(e => {
|       // remove sensitive fields
>       if (e.config?.data) delete e.config.data;
|       if (e.response?.config?.data) delete e.response.config.data;
|       super.analyticsHandler.error(`POST ${url} failed`, e);
```

My guess is the `delete` part is causing the problem but I'm not 100%. Maybe I am missing a babel plugin? The project was compiling before the eject.

Please let me know if there are any specific parts of code/config you need to see.

Thanks

EDIT:
This is the babel section in package.json:

```
  "babel": {
    "plugins":
    [
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata"
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      "@babel/preset-react",
      "@babel/preset-typescript"
    ]
  }
```

Comment: The unexcepted token seems to be coming from `e.config?.data`. Are you sure that you are using `@babel/preset-env` / [`@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining`](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-optional-chaining)?

Comment: Hi @j1mbl3s, thanks for your reply. I am using both. I've added the babel section to the question for reference. Thanks